# Send email only once when checkbox updated using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure which notifies recipients via email when an update to the form has been made. When the checkbox is clicked on the form, I would like to send it to a certain department. This is working fine. The issue is when that department completes their task, they check a different checkbox which notifies the next department and so on. The problem is that the record is being updated and the first checkbox is still checked which emails the first department twice. Is there a way I can only email each department only once? Below is what I am using in my stored procedure for logic.

```
IF @HRApproval = 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EmailAdd NVARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(2000) = '';
    DECLARE @Subject NVARCHAR(250) = '';

    SET @Body = @Body + '<p>New Employee Request Form has been approved'
    SET @Body = @Body + '<br /><p><a href="titleofwebpage.aspx?nhId=' + CAST(@IDNumber AS NVARCHAR(255)) + '">Link to NER</a></p>';

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
              @profile_name = 'MainProfile',
              @recipients = 'emailaddress',
              @from_address = 'emailaddress',
              @subject = @Subject,
              @body_format = 'HTML',
              @body = @Body;
END
```

Comment: Can you add a new field or table that keeps track of emails sent? Then you verify an email hasn't been sent before sending one.

Comment: Yep. That's actually what I did. I added a few checkbox fields for notifications and used them to track the emails. I guess that we were on the same track.